# Error of pip install paramiko (python 2.7) on DTK, Big Sur 11.0 Beta

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, paramiko, macos-big-sur

I get the following error message when I try to install paramiko. Any ideas how I could solve that issue and successfully install paramiko?

- OS:Big Sur 11.0 Beta (20A5299w)
- Xcode: Version 12.0 beta (12A8158a)

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.3.3-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpv97Jbo
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-qBzH7_/pynacl
    Complete output (36 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.3.3-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.3.3-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.3.3-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-env-Uw0cA0/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-env-Uw0cA0/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 264, in <module>
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-env-Uw0cA0/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 162, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-env-Uw0cA0/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 448, in __init__
        k: v for k, v in attrs.items()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-env-Uw0cA0/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 740, in finalize_options
        ep(self)
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-env-Uw0cA0/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 747, in _finalize_setup_keywords
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-env-Uw0cA0/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 219, in cffi_modules
        add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-env-Uw0cA0/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 49, in add_cffi_module
        execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-env-Uw0cA0/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 25, in execfile
        exec(code, glob, glob)
      File "src/bindings/build.py", line 36, in <module>
        ffi = FFI()
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-env-Uw0cA0/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 48, in __init__
        import _cffi_backend as backend
    ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_cffi_backend)
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be an outdated version of the command line tools?

Run

```
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install
```

and see if that solves the issue. Also:

```
softwareupdate --all --install --force
```

forces the update of any software in need of updating, in case.

Comment: My Xcode version is Version 12.0 beta (12A8158a) and the command line tool of that version does not solve the issue. I am trying to upgrade Xcode